# Can't resolve 'fs' in Laravel + Vue Project

Tags: node.js, laravel, vue.js, webpack, fs

please help me with this problem.

i tried to implement 'fs' dependency in vue laravel file.

i installed the dependency using **npm i fs**

and i add this line to include the library inside my **app.vue** file

```
const fs = require('fs');
```

but when i run the **npm run hot**, i got this error

ERROR in ./resources/js/vue/app.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-5[0].rules[0].use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js??vue-loader-options!./resources/js/vue/app.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&) 235:15-28 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\laragon\www\cms-laravel\resources\js\vue'

i tried to look for the solution and it looks like i need to add these lines to my **webpack.mix.js**

```
mix.webpackConfig({ node: { fs: 'empty' }})
```

So i did, but now got another error like this.

Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.

- configuration.node has an unknown property 'fs'. These properties are valid:
  object { __dirname?, __filename?, global? }
  -> Options object for node compatibility features.

and i dont think that i found any solution for this... please help me...

Here's my dependecies in package.json

```
"dependencies": {
        "fs": "0.0.1-security",
        "vue": "^2.6.14"
    }
```

Comment: You don't need to install `fs` separately. It's available by default through Laravel Mix so you can just require it as you did without explicitly listing it as a dependency.

Comment: at first i didnt install fs separately, but i got the 'Not Found Module' error...

Comment: "and i add this line to include the library inside my app.vue file" - why? It looks like you try to solve a problem that shouldn't exist in the first place

Comment: yea i just found out now that i cant use node js inside vue file.....